# LoRaWAN AES encryption in C#

Tags: aes

The LoRaWAN protocol has a specific way of encrypting data ([page 20, chapter 4.3.3.1](https://www.lora-alliance.org/portals/0/specs/LoRaWAN%20Specification%201R0.pdf)), and I'm trying to do it in C#.

First, a sequence A with blocks with a size of 16 bytes each `A1..An` is created. Then they are encrypted to get a sequence `S` of blocks `Si`:

```
Si = aes128_encrypt(K, Ai) for i = 1..n
S = S1 | S2 | .. | Sn
```

And finally the payload is encrypted:

```
(pld | pad16) xor S
truncation of the first len(payload) bytes
```

So far I managed to generate the blocks, but I'm new to cryptography and have no idea on how to proceed, can anyone help?

[Here is the encryption script in python.](https://github.com/jieter/python-lora/blob/master/lora/crypto.py#L21)

And this is the C# code I have so far:

```
public string encrypt(string payload, string dev_eui, string dev_addr, int counter_up)
{
  try
  {
    byte[] devaddr = StringToByteArray(dev_addr);
    byte[] aBlock = {
      0x01,
      0x00,
      0x00,
      0x00,
      0x00,
      0,
      devaddr[3],
      devaddr[2],
      devaddr[1],
      devaddr[0],
      (byte)(counter_up & 0xff),
      (byte)((counter_up >> 8) & 0xff),
      (byte)((counter_up >> 16) & 0xff),
      (byte)((counter_up >> 24) & 0xff),
      0x00,
      0x00 };

     \\...
```